# Web Form Builder, Open Source, Drag and Drop

Tags: forms, web, drag-and-drop, open-source

This is not a technical question, but I will try to be specific in order to this question to fit into the stackoverflow requirements.

I'm currently facing a task where I have to design hundreds of web forms, integrated in a java web project (JSP pages). I'm searching for a Web Form designer tool with the following requirements:

- Drag and Drop interface (to speed up the process);
- Open Source;
- Database access (not mandatory but at the same time very usefull);
- Java integration or Java based (again, not mandatory but at the same time very usefull);
- Capable of exporting local files (the forms can not be alocated online, like in many form builders);

I wasn't able to find a tool to fit this requirements. Does anyone knows one?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no there isn't. You can find frameworks that acts as a wrapper and therefore it can save some development time, such as http://www.jformer.com/

There are a few proprietary applications around. Take a look at http://www.wufoo.com/

I've been looking for similar tool without any success. I am thinking about starting an open source project in these lines. But, I do not have anything concrete yet...

Comment: Thanks for the time Yori...